# Por qué este código agrega el script a un text area

Tags: html, jquery

Recientemente estaba tratando de codificar y descodificar y me [ahllé un código en stackoverflow gringo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25963826/6999690) y me quedé muy sorprendido al probarlo.

```js
$("<textarea/>").html('&lt;a&gt').val() // return '<a>'
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea/>
```

Yo esperaba algo como que no le agregara ningún elemento y quedara igual de vacío pero resulta que le agrega el valor del script (y no sé si pase solamente en mi navegador firefox, pero no lo creo).

Adjunto captura por si no se ve igual:

[image: captura del resultado raro]

Comment: Parece ser que tiene que ver con cómo los exploradores web manejan algunos `self-closing tags` que esperan no estar vacios, [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-elements-work) hace referencia a este fenómeno, [está también](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729059/why-isnt-textarea-self-closing), especificamente para el tag `textarea`. Si se usa el par de `<textarea></textarea>` el problema desaparece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema no es el código JS. Es realmente un comportamiento quizás inesperado del elemento `textarea` dado que las etiquetas inicial y final son obligatorias [(ver mas aquí)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea />
```

Obtendrías un comportamiento diferente únicamente con ceñirte al uso correcto del elemto asi:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```